# Comparison test to show series diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

What other possible function could I
 compare this series to show that it diverges

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln k)^9} $$ I don't see how to compare it with the usual $\frac{1}{k}$ and other powers of it, and that is what i have tried so far. Please advise.

Comment: Ambiguity: $(\ln k)^9$ or $\ln(k^9)$?

Comment: You actually can compare with just $1\over k$ as it is less than $1\over {(\log k)^9}$ after some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare with $\frac{1}{k}$
by repeatedly using L'Hospital's rule to show
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\ln^9k}}{\frac{1}{k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k}{9!\ln k}\to \infty$$

Comment: Are you considering $\log(k^9)$ or $\log^9(k)$ ? I think that there is a big ambiguity, as pointed already by Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla

Comment: It would be easier to apply l'H\^opital to $(1/\ln k)/(1/k^{1/9})$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, after some point we will have that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{k} < \frac{1}{(\ln{k})^9} $

Now we know $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k}$ diverges (Properties of Hyperharmonic Series - see $\textbf{*}$).

$\displaystyle\stackrel{\text{B.C.T}}{\implies} \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln{k})^9} $ diverges.

> $\textbf{*}$ Convergence of Hyperharmonic Series:
>
> A series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^q}$ converges if $q >1$  and diverges if $q \leq 1$.